# How to describe the gravitational field generated by a moving particle?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Which means the formula in general relativity similar to the use of Lienard-Wiechert potentials in electromagnetism.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06507) on boosted black holes might be useful. The metric is given in eqn. 27.

Answer (score 2):

In the weak-field limit, $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ where $h_{\mu\nu} \ll 1$ is the metric perturbation. By choosing the Lorenz gauge, the Einstein field equations become a wave equation
$$\Box^2 \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = -16\pi G T_{\mu\nu}$$
where $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} - h\eta_{\mu\nu}/2$ is the trace-reversed metric perturbation. This is analogous to the electromagnetic case and can be solved with the standard Green's function involving retarded time. Otherwise, in the general case, the retarded time is already accounted for by the Einstein field equations.

Comment: All the OP needs is to write the $T$ of a particle.